# How can I tell a contract is ERC20 contract by golang

Tags: erc-20

There is one way that I can search the contract from all ERC20 contracts, but I  have to maintain a list of all ERC20 contracts, which is not very convinent, is there any interface I can use? Thx very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time EIP-20 standards was finalized, Solidity contracts did not offer any interface support.

At the moment you can only maintain a database of known compatible token contract addresses.

Comment: sad news, thx anyway

Comment: @DenverJacob Please do not forget to mark the question closed :)